# Installation of Windows Management Framework 4.0 (Powershell 4.0) on Server 2012 failed

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, dsc

I've been trying to test PowerShell Desired State configuration on a Windows Server 2012 instance on Amazon EC2. I downloaded the Windows Management Framework 4.0 from the MS download center:

**Windows Management Framework 4.0**

http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=40855

When attempting to install, I encoutered the following error:

> Windows update  could not be installed because of error 2148098050
>   "The certificate for the signer of the message is invalid or not
>   found." (Command line: ""C:\Windows\system32\wusa.exe"
>   "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Windows6.1-KB2819745-x64-MultiPkg.msu"
>   ")

Code signed installers normally include the certificate as part of the binary. I just right-clicked on the package and extracted the certificate manually from the MSU and installed it in the local machine certificate store to ensure the signer was trusted. When I tried to install the package again, I received a new error:

> Windows update  could not be installed because of error 2148073480
>   "Invalid algorithm specified." (Command line:
>   ""C:\Windows\system32\wusa.exe"
>   "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\Windows6.1-KB2819745-x64-MultiPkg.msu"
>   ")

Can any one please help with resolving the above issue ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was downloading the wrong file. The correct file for Server 2012 was the following (from the same link posted in the question):

> Windows8-RT-KB2799888-x64.msu

Installing the MSU above worked flawlessly.